# React Native Android setup details

Tags: react-native

With the release of React Native 0.29 the details about how to setup the env for Android were removed for all I can tell. Does anyone know why?

It seems like the steps mentioned in there are still necessary, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the previous versions and view their docs easily. Just click on the `Version Number` found beside the React Native header. It'll list all the versions and the link to documents.

[Archive lists](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/versions.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that, yet still ran into issues. I had deleted all my Android stuff before to do a clean reinstall. After installing Android studio again (following the guide from 0.28) ReactNative always gives me an error when it tries to install the app on a simulator (AVD never worked anyway, but Genymotion did). And I thought that maybe the latest studio might need somewhat different settings (yes, I tried to find a solution for the error but couldn't find any so far).

Comment: @north Can you provide the error? I've the latest Android Studio and it's running fine.

Comment: That setup is running on a machine I don't have access to atm, so I could only post the error message later on...

Comment: It's working again. I did a few things, so I'm not 100% sure what fixed it, but I think the device I had installed in Genymotion came with the wrong API version